# Angular - How can I mock an HTTP request?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a simple code which invokes a real HTTP request :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{person?.id}}</h2>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  constructor(public http: Http) {
     this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
     .map(res => res.json()).subscribe(res => {
        this.person = res;
     },()=>{},()=>console.log('complete'));    
  }
}
```

But now I want to mock the request so that it will fetch data from a file containing :

```
export arrFakeData:any = {id:1};
```

I don't want to use a service . I want to mock the request.
Some examples shows to use `XHRBackend` and some shows how to [extend](http://www.adonespitogo.com/articles/angular-2-extending-http-provider/) the HTTP class,  but they doesn't say how can I force the data to retrieve

I know that I should use

```
  providers:[ /*{ provide: XHRBackend, useClass: MockBackend }*/]
```

But I don't know how.

**Question:**

How can I mock http request and return (for GET) the array from `arrFakeData` ?

[**PLUNKER**](https://plnkr.co/edit/9Q44FgNsBqLiUlEGrBAW?p=preview)

Comment: Hi Royi, do you want to use this for development or for testing?

Comment: @ash hi. Neither. I already know the webapi plug in , I just want to know how to do it plain simple by myself

Comment: If you want to use it just for developing. Make a json file with the response data from your API url. Then in the `http.get(path_to_json)`

Comment: @YordanNikolov The whole point is to change it in one place and not start replacing string in the code. :)  BTW my question was for knowing how to `providers:[ /*{ provide: XHRBackend, useClass: MockBackend }*/]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I would replace the `this.http.get` method call with an `Observable.of` so that you can continue programming against the same interface (`Observable`) without impacting the development of your components.

However, if you really want to do this then you will have to create a service that attaches a listener to all the incoming requests and returns an appropriate mock response using the tools provided by the `@angular/http/testing` module.

The service will look something as such:

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {MockBackend, MockConnection} from "@angular/http/testing";
import {arrFakeData} from "./fakeData";
import {ResponseOptions, Response} from "@angular/http";

@Injectable()
export class MockBackendService {
    constructor(
        private backend: MockBackend
    ) {}

    start(): void {
        this.backend.connections.subscribe((c: MockConnection) => {
            const URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1";

            if (c.request.url === URL) { // You can also check the method
                c.mockRespond(new Response(new ResponseOptions({
                    body: JSON.stringify(arrFakeData)
                })));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Once you have done this, you need to register all the services and make sure that the `Http` module is using the `MockBackend` instead of the `XHRBackend`.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, HttpModule,],
  declarations: [App],
  providers: [
    MockBackend,
    MockBackendService,
    BaseRequestOptions,
    {
      provide: Http,
      deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions],
      useFactory: (backend: MockBackend, options: BaseRequestOptions) => {
        return new Http(backend, options);
      }
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [App]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Last but not least, you have to actually invoke the `start` method, which will make sure that you will actually receive the mock data from the `MockBackend`. In your `AppComponent` you can do the following.

```
constructor(public http: Http, public mockBackendService: MockBackendService) {
  this.mockBackendService.start();

  this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(res => {
      this.person = res;
    });
}
```

I hope this helps! See the plunker for the full example. https://plnkr.co/edit/h111to5PxbI97FIyKGJZ?p=preview

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thank you. BTW - I know that there is another alternative which is to use `{ provide: XHRBackend, useClass: MockBackend }` will it be rude to ask for a plunker with the `{ provide: XHRBackend, useClass: MockBackend }` approach ?

Answer (score 1):

You can just make the http endpoint a JSON file containing whatever data you need. This is exactly how we did it on my last project for Google, and how I do it in my own side projects. We didn't bother mocking up http services and so on, we just pointed at a json file and left everything else the same.